# How to iterate through object array with form helpes in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, formhelper

I have an object CuratedPage with property pageName.

I am creating an array of CuratedPage objects in controller and setting it for the view like this:

```
$this->set('curatedPages', $curatedPages);
```

In the view I am creating a dropdown of page names like this:

```
$pageNames = array();
foreach($curatedPages as $curatedPage) {
    array_push($pageNames, $curatedPage->getPageName());
}
echo $this->Form->input('curatedPage', array('options' => $pageNames));
```

Is there a way in cakephp that will allow me to pass the array of CuratedPage objects to the Form->input(...) instead of creating an array of scalar values.

Comment: I don't think so.. but you could move that array creating code into your controller instead of having it in the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you would expect the form helper to do in that case. However, depending on your PHP version (>= 5.2.0 required) the magic [`__toString()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) method might do it. If you implement it to return the pagename, then you would end up with the same result as with your posted snippet, ie an numerical indexed (the value attribute) HTML option list with the page names as labels.

However, implementing this only for that purpose in this specific view seems wrong to me, you're probably better of utilizing a custom helper, or as [@BrianGlaz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18258406/how-to-iterate-through-object-array-with-form-helpes-in-cakephp#comment26777351_18258406) suggested prepare the data in the controller.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to achieve something like this:   <g:select from="${curatedPages}" name="curatedPage" optionValue="${curatedPage?.slug}"/> This code snippet is from groovy.

Comment: Well, CakePHP isn't Grails, and PHP isn't Groovy (no pun intended :)), the `FormHelper` doesn't work that way, as mentioned, implementing `__toString()` will give you the same results as with your PHP snippet. This specific Grails tag however would, AFAIU, use the result of `CuratedPage.toString()` for the `option` elements `value` attribute, and the value of `CuratedPage.slug` for the `option` elements body, and that's totally different from how the `FormHelper` works. Again, using a helper that prepares the `options` array, or preparing it the controller would probably be your best bet.